# moving a form by holding on a label

Tags: c#, forms, window, label, mouseevent

I am trying to create a label which is centred within a form which requires me to use the `label.dock = dockStyle.Fill`. Therefore I tried implementing code which means that when I hold down on the label I can move the form around. This is what i have so far:

```
private void messageIndicator_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        window.AllowTransparency = true;
        window.TransparencyKey = window.TransparencyKey = window.BackColor;
        isDragging = false;
    }

    void messageIndicator_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        window.AllowTransparency = false;
    }

    private void messageIndicator_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the drag mode
        isDragging = true;

        // Get the initial location
        lastLocation = e.Location;
    }

    private void messageIndicator_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Only drag if in correct state (mouse down)
        if (isDragging)
        {
            // The parameter sender is the form object
            Form f = (Form)sender;

            // Calculate the new location and update the form
            f.Location = new Point((f.Location.X - lastLocation.X) + e.X, (f.Location.Y - lastLocation.Y) + e.Y);
            f.Update();
        }
    }
```

`messageIndicator` being the label on the form. It does crash when `Form f = (form)sender` is executed. Help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: No, the sender must be the `Label`. What exception does it raise?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Pear GIS.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

private void YourLabel_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{     
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
    }
}
```

Source: [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11114/Move-window-form-without-Titlebar-in-C)

Comment: Error 176 The name 'Handle' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Khal786 Sorry for very late, if you have not solved this issue yet then please show your code.

Comment: @Khal786 If you are working in within the form then no issue will be there regarding `Handle`.